# Simplifying Circuits

Tags: computer-architecture, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

[image]

I have a question regarding simplifying a circuit of a function below that has 5 logic gates in original.

f = (A + B) * (C + D) + (A + B) * (C + D)' + C

= (A + B) * ((C + D) + (C + D)') + C

= (A + B) * 1 + C Complement

= (A + B) + C

Now, I have reduced to 2 logic gates from 5. But, here, am I allowed to change (A + B) + C to A + B + C, so that I can reduce number of gates (i.e., 1 logic gate) even more? If I am allowed, is there a name for this process (what kind of law is this)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Previously asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1126470/18398

Comment: You should always link to multiple instances of the same question whenever you ask the same question on different StackExchange sites.

Comment: I assume that (A+B)*(C+D)' means ((A+B)*((C+D)').  Wouldn't your original need 6 logic gates?  Did you count the NOT gate in (C+D)'?  (Remember, you also have a (C+D) term.)

Comment: Also, what is the word "Complement" in the third line about?  It seems like it shouldn't be there.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche It's just a tag for complement law which states x+x'=1.

Comment: That's a very unusual AND gate (the one with one inverted input).  Are you sure this is allowed?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche The task I was given is just to simplify the given circuit and have the least number of gates, so I guess I can't say anything about what you said is allowed or not in the real world..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can change the two 2-input OR gates to one 3-input OR gate.  As for it being "allowed," that depends.  Who is the one giving permission?  If it's a teacher, then you should ask her/him what is "allowed."  I am not familiar with any formal name for this substitution.

Comment: As was mentioned in the comments and an answer in the MSE version of this question, the name for this "process" is *associativity*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also plot the equation using the technique called Karnaugh Mapping and visually see how your equation simplifies down.  Look for an explanation of Karnaugh Mapping here:

http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/elessonshtml/Logic/Logic3.html

Comment: We like answers here to at least be self-contained with the basic information.  In this case, it would be good to give some idea what Karnaugh maps are, then you can use a link for more detail.